# What do the lyrics for Frisco Town from Memphis Minnie (1929) mean?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

I haven't a perfect knowledge of English, and history and country/blues music from the 20's sometimes carries images that I can't figure clearly.

In her song [Frisco Town](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXTo28Dw3yE), in 1929, what does *Memphis Minnie* mean?
What's the purpose of the song? It's obviously telling a story or about something common then, but what?

> That old 'Frisco train makes a mile a minute
> That old 'Frisco train makes a mile a minute
> Well, in that old coach, I'm gonna sit right in it
> I'm on my way, to 'Frisco town
>
> You can toot your whistle, you can ring your bell
> You can toot your whistle, you can ring your bell
> But I know you been wanting it by the
> way you smell
> I'm on my way to 'Frisco town
>
> There's a boa constrictor and a lemon stick
> There's a boa constrictor and a lemon stick
> I don't mind being with you but my mama's sick
> I'm on my way to 'Frisco town
>
> I would tell you what's the matter, but I done got scared
> I would tell you what's the matter, but I done got scared
> You got to wait now, until we go to bed
> I'm on my way to 'Frisco town
>
> If you was sick, I wouldn't worry you
> If you was sick, I wouldn't worry you
> I wouldn't want you to do something that you couldn't do
> I'm on my way to 'Frisco town
>
> Well, if you want it, you can get it, and I ain't mad
> Well, if you want it, you can get it, and I ain't mad
> If you tell me this is something that you ain't never had
> I'm on my way to 'Frisco town
>
> Look-a here, you get mad everytime I call your name
> Look-a here, you get mad everytime I call your name
> I ain't never told you that you couldn't get that thing
> I'm on my way to 'Frisco town
>
> I woke up this morning about half past five
> I woke up this morning about half past five
> My baby turned over, cried just like a child
> I'm on my way to 'Frisco town
>
> I got something to tell you, I don't want to make you mad
> I got something to tell you, I don't want to make you mad
> I got something for you, make you feel glad
> I'm on my way to 'Frisco town
>
> Look-a here, look-a here, what you want me to do
> Look-a here, look-a here, what you want me to do
> Give you my jelly, then die for you
> I'm on my way to 'Frisco town
>
> I got something to tell you, gonna break your heart
> I got something to tell you, gonna break your heart
> We been together so far, we gotta get apart
> I'm on my way to 'Frisco town

Comment: tbh, I don't think it's your English language skills that are lacking here - that's a pretty obscure set of references, which as a native speaker I would have trouble sorting out. Wish you well now this has been migrated to Music Fans.

Comment: Good thanks for that move! I didn't know and enjoys this new stack!

Comment: "It's obviously telling a story or about something common then, but what?" --Sex.